# How to create a single page application in Drupal?

Tags: ajax, javascript

I know Drupal and now I am creating a website by Laravel framework. I know what are single page application and how better they are. I used Angular and Backbone as JavaScript framework/library to creating a single page application with Laravel.

I am not professional in Drupal, How can I use these libraries to create a single page application (SPA) using Drupal?

Is there any module to make a (SPA) or automatically make the website Full-Ajax?

Comment: This should be handy: https://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/how-create-single-page-apps-drupal-may-28-2013

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Ajax Regions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_regions) module.

It allows you to load specific regions via Ajax, thus load your whole website on one single page

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following modules. (They are very different despite similar names.) You can find demo links for each module in their pages.

[Single Page Website](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_website)

> This module provide the ability to display the content of all menu items of the main-menu on the Single Page Website module.
>
> On the page 'single_page' the links in the menu will be replaced to the links to the correspondent anchors.
> You can set URL 'single_page' as front page of your site, and your visitors will see the Single Page Website. But it will be the site managed by Drupal 7.

[Single Page Site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site)

> This module provides functionality to create a single page website.
>
> It allows you to automatically create a single page from a menu. The module will render all the content from the links, that are configured in the menu, on one page. It will then override the menu links so that they refer to an anchor instead of a new page. With some additional css you can develop a horizontal single page site.

Comment: Single page site is not theme dependent, single page website is

Comment: What? This is not usable for me! I think you did't read the question as well.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I am kidding, sorry if I make you sad. :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a single page app using Drupal I would recommend you look into the [services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) to create your end points and then use the [Backbone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/backbone) for creating front end logic. Whilst there isn't a stable release of the Backbone module we are using it on a production website without any problems.

If you Google "Drupal single page app" there are a few talks about it that come up.

The company I work for has a Druapl 7 single page app and it works well, but it pretty complex stuff - not something to take on if you don't know what your doing.